# Google API For Website Classification Project

Tags: php

im doing a project in which will use google api 
can anyone post a link for an Api or an Api as i can use that api in my project

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. I *think* you're asking us to link you to a Google API? Regardless, please review the FAQ about which questions you should ask here. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: Please revise your question here.  We are not here to do research for you.  If you are looking for help on a certain API, post a new question here and maybe we can help you out, Please research a little bit before posting your question here.  doing a simple google search for "Google Api" is a good place to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html